# Error in loading drawImage() method in Javascript canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, onload, drawimage

I have the following class inside my code:

```
//Collectables
const humanImg = new Image();
humanImg.src = "../images/human.png";
const mutationImg = new Image();
mutationImg.src = "../images/mutation.png";
//Canvas
const mycanvas = document.getElementById('my-canvas');
let ctx = mycanvas.getContext('2d');
//Classes
class Collectable {
    constructor(img, x, y, width, height) {
        this.img = img;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.collected = false;
        this.notScored = true;
        this.mutate = false;
    };
    draw(){
        ctx.drawImage(this.img, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    };
    checkcollision(object) {
        return (
          this.x < object.x + object.width &&
          this.x + this.width > object.x &&
          this.y < object.y + object.height &&
          this.y + this.height > object.y
        );
    };
    collect(object){
        if (this.checkcollision(object)) {
            this.collected = true;
            ctx.clearRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
            ctx.fillStyle = "black";
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
            this.mutate = true;
        };
    };
    updateScore(object, score){
        if ((this.checkcollision(object)) && (this.notScored === true)){
            points += score;
            pointsRestart += score;
            this.notScored = false;
            playerMovingAudio.play();
            playerMovingAudio.volume = 0.6;
        };
    };
};
```

And later on the code when I calle the class Collectable:

```
// Collectables
const specialCollects = [
    new Collectable(mutationImg, 20, 60, 30, 30),
    new Collectable(mutationImg, 950, 60, 30, 30),
    new Collectable(mutationImg, 20, 500, 30, 30),
    new Collectable(mutationImg, 950, 500, 30, 30)
];
```

I get an error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The HTMLImageElement provided is in the 'broken' state.
```

And I don't know how to solve it, the error is on this line:

```
ctx.drawImage(this.img, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
```

Inside the class Collectable. I have tried to add and onload event on that line but the error is still there. What can I do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved this problem changing the js file to the root. I think it took time looking for the images because it had to look between two folders, I had the js file inside a folder called \js before. So thank you!